# PWM signal for DC motor vs voicecoil

Tags: motor, pwm, oscilloscope, driver

I'm working on a project where I want to design my own current driver to drive different kind of loads. A friend of mine lent me a motor, an Arduino UNO to generate the PWM and half-bridge IC (L293D) to control a motor as a practice.

To test the design the following topology has been followed (with the bottom part of the DC motor connected to ground).

[image: Image 1]

Three different loads (R, L and the motor) were tested under the following conditions:

1. PWM signal's frequency was 1 KHz and the duty cycle used for these examples was 25%.
2. Supply voltages for the Arduino and the L293D were 5V.
3. The resistive load was bigger than 10k, the inductance had 0.9 mH with a DC resistance of 2.2 Ohm (+4.7 series resistor that I added to not burn the IC), and I don't have the specs for the motor.

When measured the output with the oscilloscope (between the output of the L293D and ground) the results for the resistive load and for the voicecoil made sense. The resistive load showed the PWM signal without any distortion, and the voicecoil load showed the expected distortion due to the effect of the inductance against current changes (Images 2 and 3).

However, when connected to a motor, the voltage levels that appear in the oscilloscope become weird (Image 4). For instance, the Vpp it's not 5V anymore, some of the power falls between the input and the output of the L293D. Also, the voltage never reaches 0 level. At first I thought it was because a motor's equivalent circuit it's not only an inductance, but nevertheless I think I should see the whole PWM signal at the output, and not just a small fraction of it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**While writing the question it occurred to me that the resistive DC value of the motor could be way small. Could that be one reason? Or what's the motive behind this behaviour?

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Comment: Your motor seems to use about 230mA current. The L293D is specified in the datasheet as follows: At max. 600mA, the output will drop about 1.4V from top or buttom supply. So at 1/3 of this current I would expect a drop of 0.5V from top or bottom supply, which is 0.5V to 4.5V.

Is this what you are seeing on the scope? (Maybe you have some additional resistance due to poor cabling)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did think about the Darlingtong output to be the problem, but I thought I should see the same with the other 2 loads, which doesn't happen. Which, btw, is weir because I would expect to have that drop also with the other 2 loads but doesn't happen either.